# "Attribute class is not allowed here" in xml file Android studio 3.4 error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-3.4

Attribute class is not allowed here error. I don't know what is causing this error

```
Android studio :3.4
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0"
```

[image: error]

Comment: Try to make alt+Enter and see what the suggestions given

Comment: @ParthPatel its says remove which I don't want to do

Comment: Have you tried it after update Gradle Version?

Comment: @ParthPatel that's the latest verison

Comment: Is it com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 ?

Comment: yes!!. just got an update, it's an android studio bug. Updated answer as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that it's android studio 3.4 error, this should probably go after an Android update or for now downgrade the version works.

Note: it does not run into any errors if you run with the same version

**Update:**
Android studio update 3.4.1 removes this issue

Answer (score 1):

I have same thing but when i do clean and build project it successfully build and run application.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really help :(

Comment: Same thing its only in Android Studio 3.4 latest update before its working good.

Comment: you can ignore this as of now, it just shows it in red color but you won't run into errors. You can probably find it resolved in next update

Answer (score -5):

No need to use data class in XML we directly initialize that XML in Java Class.

Example: - There is an XML class activity_course.xml we can Directly initialize in Java Class By Using "ActivityCourseBinding".

Happy Coding !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This isn't a solution, this is a workaround. And not a specifically good one.

Comment: I already implemented in my application it is working now@Zoe